# what does the regular expression (?<!-) mean

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to understand a piece of code and came across this regular expression used in PHP's preg_replace function.

```
'/(?<!-)color[^{:]*:[^{#]*$/i'
```

This bit... `(?<!-)` 
doesnt appear in any of my reg-exp manuals. Anyone know what this means please? (Google doesnt return anything - I dont think symbols work in google.)

Comment: It is a smiley of Batman's enemy hit in the left eye but smiling anyway... (but it will match anyone wearing a similar hat)

Comment: For reference: [Look-Around Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) from perlre, [Positive and Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) on regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `?<!` at the start of a parenthetical group is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It asserts that the word `color` (strictly, the `c` in the engine) was not preceded by a `-` character.

So, for a more concrete example, it would match `color` in the strings:

```
color
+color
someTextColor
```

But it will fail on something like `-color` or `background-color`. Also note that the engine will not technically "match" whatever precedes the `c`, it simply asserts that it is not a hyphen. This can be an important distinction depending on the context ([illustrated on Rubular with a trivial example](http://rubular.com/r/vfjHHLxpyc); note that *only* the `b` in the last string is matched, not the preceding letter).

Answer (score 6):

PHP uses perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE) for the preg_* functions. From `perldoc perlre`:

> `"(?<!pattern)"`
>      A zero-width negative look-behind assertion.  For example
>     `"/(?<!bar)foo/"` matches any occurrence of "foo" that does
>      not follow `"bar"`.  Works only for fixed-width look-
>      behind.

Comment: @Gumbo - That would have been better. I cited the perldoc because I knew exactly where to find the information.

Answer (score 4):

I'm learning regular expressions using Python's re module!

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

> Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion. Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length. Patterns which start with negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the string being searched.

Comment: Python regex is not PCRE like PHP's.

Comment: Understandable, I just thought I'd point out another regular expression library, I'm new to regular expressions so I'm trying to learn as much as I can about regular expressions in most major languages so I thought I'd point out Python's.